# How do i restore from staged into working directory

Tags: git

How do i restore from staged into working directory? in other words i want the working directory to look like how it did after my last `git add`.

This is what i did:

1. `git add foo.md`
2. edit edit edit(no add, nothing)

How do i go back to how my working directory looked just after number 1?

I have tried doing `git stash` then `git stash pop --index` but it seems to bring back edits that weren't staged. and at that point i would probably just commit and then reset. Is there a command though, to just bring back my staged?

Comment: You want to keep the change or is it ok to lost them ?

Comment: ty for replying @Ôrel, i want to keep the staged but loose the recent edits

Comment: `git reset --hard`  will bring you to the last commited state (/!\ you will lost all uncommitted changes)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To retrieve state of `path/to/file` from index use `git restore path/to/file`.

See manual page of [`git-restore`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-restore) for details and other options.

Comment: ty this worked. @chepner i think what --staged option does is it moves the file from into the working directory, leaving nothing in the index which works for what i want as well but i didn't specify that i also wanted it to be kept in the index i just wanted to discard the recent edits i made. if i did do that, i can easily `git add` them again

Comment: My bad; I got the directions reversed. `git restore` does restore from the index, not from `HEAD`.